# Discord Bot Not Responding (node.js)

Tags: discord.js

I've skimmed through the code of my discord bot and can't find out whats wrong since it isn't responding to any commands. It says its online but it doesn't respond to anything.
Can someone find the issue?

`your text`
https://pastebin.com/RJFVqLGJ

I typed node . in the terminal then tried to maske the bot respond and nothing happened.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as a link to a pastebin which often would be obsoleted later on, making your post unhelpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please learn how to ask a question before posting a question. Your post doesn't show any errors and what you have done to attempt on fixing the issue. Please read the side panel when creating a post.

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Answer (score 0):

Since an update to Discord a few months back your bot needs to specify `Intents`. These are flags that just tell Discord what you want to do with the bot. What you're missing:

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    ],
});
```

Discord.JS Docs: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#gateway-intents

also don't forget to import the client as described in the docs's example

Comment: Now it says in the terminal:

ReferenceError: Client is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\CodingProjects\DiscordBot\bot.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Comment: I believe your answer has no errors but please include parameters in a comment to avoid confusion to @Ultimate as it is likely that he has a low understanding of Javascript and this would help them understand what Client is defined as.